Azure Bastion sometimes uses public DNS name instead of VM name as tab title
I'm connecting to multiple Azure VMs using Bastion RDP (each connected VM is in a separate Google Chrome tab) and I noticed that some tabs use the VMs name, while others use the public DNS name of the Bastion instead.
I can't easily reproduce this, I tried closing the tabs and reconnecting and now every tab shows the VM name.
It doesn't have that big of an impact, it's just harder to navigate between tabs since they don't all display a significative name.
I checked the VMs settings and the Bastion settings and they all seem to be similar between the VMs, I didn't find any setting similar to "tab name" either.
The only possible solution I found was the Instance Count setting in the Configuration tab of my Bastion which was set to 2. Since the first time I noticed the problem, I had two tabs displaying the VM name and the other 3 were displaying the DNS name so I thought the Instance count had something to do with it but once again, when I restarted the connections, all tabs were displaying the VM names so that's probably not it.
I'm fairly new to Azure so any help or hint will be appreciated.


Azure Bastion sometimes uses public DNS name instead of VM name as tab title

If the VM's browser tab is displaying the public DNS name instead of the VM name due to network connectivity or browser cache issues, you may need to clear the browser cache and restart the browser.
Unfortunately, there is no setting in Azure Bastion to control the tab name display once you are connected to a VM.
One alternative is to rename the VMs to more descriptive names, which will be displayed in the tab title and help identify each VM
If you are working with multiple browser tabs, you can use a tab extension to help you identify each tab more easily.
You will find that the Bastion session details and tab names are also displayed with the same target hostname when you open any tab.

Bastion tab names

Refer: Connect to VM via  bastion
Troubleshoot Azure Bastion
